# mysterious .N object in global environment after installing R package

Tags: r, devtools

I have created a package for personal use that has some dependencies:

```
Depends: R (>= 3.2.3), data.table (>= 1.9.6), bit64 (>= 0.9.5), 
         ggplot2 (>= 2.0.0), yaml (>= 2.1.13)
```

When I install this package via `devtools::install()` it completes with no error.

When I load the package in a fresh session via `library(somePackage)` 
I get the cryptic message:

> Attaching package: ‘data.table’
>
> The following object is masked *by* ‘.GlobalEnv’:
>
> .N

There are no objects in the global environment -- I try `ls()`, which returns an empty string, clear workspace [broom icon], etc.  Yet:

```
> .N
[1] 100419
```

which has no meaning to me -- I know what `.N` is in data.table but have no idea where 100419 came from.  How can I tell which environment in the search path this is really going to?

```
> search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"           "package:somePackage"  "package:devtools"     "package:yaml"        
 [5] "package:ggplot2"      "package:bit64"        "package:bit"          "package:data.table"  
 [9] "tools:rstudio"        "package:stats"        "package:graphics"     "package:grDevices"   
[13] "package:utils"        "package:datasets"     "package:methods"      "Autoloads"           
[17] "package:base"
```

I believe that the dependencies are part of the cause, because when I remove this line from the DESCRIPTION file, I do not have this problem.

Running `devtools` `1.10.0` on `R 3.2.3` for Windows.

**update:** thanks to the hint from @MrFlick:

```
> ls(all.names=TRUE)
[1] ".N"           ".Random.seed"
```

So it is in the global environment, but how did it get there and why does it take precedence?

Comment: `ls()` hides names that begin with a period. Try `ls(all.names=TRUE)`. Is this after a fresh R restart? Are you loading an existing workspace? Also `getAnywhere(".N")` should show where variables are coming from.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for the suggestion!  Please see update -- plus Yes fresh R restart, no existing workspace  Ah -- if I clear the environment with "remove hidden objects" toggled it goes away and does not mask data.table.

Comment: Are you runninng everything inside RStudio?

Comment: @Pascal yes,  v0.99.879

Comment: Same version of RStudio, but `ls(all.names=TRUE)` only gives `".Random.seed"`. Did you defined a `.N` from somewhere? Knowing that `.N` is a variable defined in package `data.table`.

Comment: @Pascal I must have done so, but obviously it's not a reproducible problem.  I'm probably going to delete the question.  Thanks for your interest.

Comment: No problem. Sorry to not be more helpful.

Comment: Perhaps it was saved in .Rhistory or .Rdata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same message when loading `data.table`. No idea when I loaded `.N` so I went for the following:

1. Checking all variables to see what I have:

   `ls(all.names=TRUE)`
2. Removing all varaibles:

   `rm(list = ls(all.names=TRUE))`